# Visual Studio WinForm Bug Or Am I Doing Something Wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm that mysteriously changes height seemingly randomly.  Usually everything is evenly spaced, but sometimes when I look back at my form, it has a large margin under the bottom button.

screenshot: http://min.us/mv00PK

This is pretty weird, I'm not sure what's going on here, but I hate changing it back each time it happens.  Whatever the case may be, I'm not manually changing the height so that gap is there, but could I be doing something else that causes this to happen?

Please let me know if you have an idea of what's happening here, thanks!

Comment: It's very hard to know what's happening without seeing any code.

Comment: Without even reading the question: You are doing something wrong.

Comment: After 200+ questions you should be able to pick a better title.

Comment: shrinking in VB6 was linked to limited amount of memory, but never seen expanding. It could be your mouse

Comment: @Henk: Right, because there are no bugs in VS, especially when it comes to the designer.  I have had this same exact thing happen to me in the designer.  We have an app in house that resizes to fit the designer window if you build the project with said designer window open.  Please let me know how you can attribute that to user error.

Comment: @Ed: If you have a Button @ Bottom-right that is anchored to the default Top-Left than that is user error. Anyway, this title is wrong even if it is a VS bug. On many levels.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not disputing that.  You said "you are doing something wrong" based completely on the title, which in turn indicates that you don't think there is any way it could possibly be a VS bug.  I don't see how you can make that assumption without reading the question.

Comment: @Soo, you are not providing enough information to help you. At least tell us whether this is happening in the VS designer, debugger, or in running the WinForm app.

Comment: @Henk: I don't get the reference, but that is probably due to the two glasses of scotch I just had compounded by the fact that it is 12:33 p.m.  Ok, now I feel like an old man admitting I drink scotch to wind down :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override or subscribe to the form size changed event, and set a breakpoint in it in the debugger. This will let you know what operation it is that causes the form to change size. From there, you should be able to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

> when I look back at my form, it has a large margin under the bottom button

There are about a dozen factors involved (FormBorderStyle, ScaleMode, FontSize, Anchors, Docking, ...).

You mentioned exactly 0 of them.

> I'm not sure what's going on here

Neither are we.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the gap appearing consistently, yuo can consider setting the `MaximumSize` property of the form to the desired size. That should prevent it from *growing*.